# Form submission with JS enabled and JS disabled

Tags: jquery, ajax

Right now I have two methods for submitting a form--one if Javascript is enabled (ajax form submission, submitting to process.php) and one if Javascript is not enabled (submits to index.php). However, right now I have Javascript enabled and the JQ/Ajax submit is not working because the page is refreshing.

index.php:

```
<?php
    include_once('TaskDB.php');
    include_once('task.php');

// JAVASCRIPT DISABLED

    if(isset($_POST['description_text']) && isset($_POST['deadline_text'])){
        $description = $_POST['description_text'];
        $duration = $_POST['duration_text'];
        $deadline = $_POST['deadline_text'];

        // create a new task object, add it to database
        $task = new Task('DEFAULT', $description, $duration, $deadline, '0');
        TaskDB::addTask($task);
        // to prevent re-submission upon refreshing the page
        header('Location: index.php');
    }


<!doctype html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"/>
    <title>Taskage</title>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#task_form').submit(function(e){
                $.post('process.php', $("#task_form").serialize(), function(data){

                    // clear the current task table
                    $('#form').nextAll('tr').empty();

                    // refresh the task table with the newly inserted task
                    $(data).insertAfter('#form');
                });
                e.preventDefault();
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="topframe">
        <div id="logo"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="nav">
        <table id = nav_table>
        <tr>
            <td><a href="index.php"><img src="images/tab1m.png" class="navimg" id="tab1"/></a></td>
            <td><a href="completed.php"><img src="images/tab2.png" class="navimg" id="tab2"/></a></td>
            <td><a href="failed.php"><img src="images/tab3.png" class="navimg" id="tab3"/></a></td>
            <td><a href="settings.php"><img src="images/tab4.png" class="navimg" id="tab4"/></a></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    </div>

    <div id="main_area">
        <h2>Tasks</h2>

        <table id = "tasks_table">
        <tr>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Hours</th>
            <th>Task</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
        <tr id = "form">
            <form action="index.php" method="POST" id="task_form">
                <td><input type="text" id="deadline_text" name="deadline_text"/></td>
                <td><input type="text" id="duration_text" name="duration_text"/></td>
                <td><input type="text" id="description_text" name="description_text"/></td>
                <td><input type="submit" value="Add Task" id="task_submit"/></td>
            </form>
        </tr>

        <?php
            TaskDB::generateTaskTable();
        ?>

        </table>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Process.php:

```
<?php

include_once('TaskDB.php');
include_once('task.php');

if(isset($_POST['description_text']) && isset($_POST['deadline_text'])){
    $description = $_POST['description_text'];
    $duration = $_POST['duration_text'];
    $deadline = $_POST['deadline_text'];

    // create a new task object, add it to database
    $task = new Task('DEFAULT', $description, $duration, $deadline, '0');
    TaskDB::addTask($task);
    TaskDB::generateTaskTable();


}

?>
```

There's a preventDefault() for whenever the form is submitted so I can't figure out why the page is refreshing. Any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Are you seeing any errors in your error console?

Comment: "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined (index.php:9)" and "GET https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js  (index.php:5). I'm having trouble figuring out why I'm getting these errors.

Comment: That means jQuery didn't load. Check your network log - what response code came back for Google CDN jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that the address you're using using to pull in jQuery has a `https` protocol.  It might be being blocked by the browser if your site is not `https`.  Try to change it to `http` instead.

In other words, seems like your jQuery isn't being loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I realized the reason that JQuery wasn't loading was because my CMOS battery recently died and my date and time was off (it was set to 2009), so the security certificates weren't letting load certain pages and, I'm assuming, prevented me from loading Google's JQ. After resetting the time and date, it began loading correctly. Odd!

Thanks for the responses and help though!

Comment: Yep, I have to wait two days before I can. Thanks.